# How to exit all thread when one returns

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I have the following piece of code that is supposed to simulate mining bitcoin but I'm running each "node" on it's own thread. What I'm trying to do is let all nodes start mining at the same time but when one of them is done, the others should stop. For some reason this isn't working. What is currently happening is apparently only the first node is allowed to mine while the others do nothing.

```
    chosen = self.nodes
    q = Queue()

    # to simulate concurrent mining, each client will get their own thread
    # and when one of them finds a correct nonce, the others will stop

    for node in chosen:
        Thread(target=node.mine, args=(txdata, lastblock, q)).start()
        return q.get()
```

`node.mine()` simply tries finding a hash of a block and a nonce (which always starts from 0 for all nodes) that starts with 5 zeros. The way I'm making some nodes mine faster than others is that they each have a random number representing their power and in `node.mine()`, each node sleeps for `1/power` seconds before they do anything.

Comment: `q.get()` blocks until something is available to read, effectively serializing all the threads.

Comment: @bnaecker So what should I do?

Comment: Move `q.get()` out of the `for` loop. But how do you intend to stop the other threads?

Comment: You would run real miners in separate processes, since they are CPU-bound. Threads would just add overhead to the process without providing any speed-up.

Comment: Start all threads before you read from the queue. But that won't solve your problem of stopping the remaining threads when one finishes. You need something like `threading.Event()` or some other communication mechanism.

Comment: @chepner It actually depends on whether `node.mine()` can release the GIL or not. If it can, (as is the case e.g. for `numpy`) then you still  get a speed-up from threads.

Comment: The way to solve this really depends on the `node.mine()` method. Can you post that code?

Comment: @bnaecker Its a somewhat complicated function that spans several files so its going to be a mess if I post it. I'll edit the post to explain how it works though.

Comment: You must make all threads listen to a `threading.Event()` and to be able to act on it every so often. Then, when one thread is done, and you  get the result back, you send an event to all others to quit. They will then have to be written so that they actually do quit, once they receive the event.

Comment: Is the program going to exit when these worker threads finish?

Comment: @bnaecker No, not necessarily

Comment: Then the event mechanism or other IPC is pretty much the only viable solution. Does the `node.mine()` method have a loop? Is it made up of a series of relatively fast computations? Or is it one or more very long, expensive computations?

Comment: @bnaecker It has a while loop that keeps on going until a SHA256 hash of a certain format is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was pointed out in the comments, the fact that only one thread is running at one time is because the `q.get()` call is inside the loop. This blocks until a result is ready, which effectively serializes the threads. Moving that outside the loop will start all threads before checking the queue.

However, this does not solve your problem of exiting other threads when one finishes. The "best" way to do this really depends on the structure of the `node.mine()` method.

For example, if it's a loop of some kind, generally like:

```
while True:
    relatively_fast_computation()
```

then you can add a `threading.Event()` or similar to the mix, and have each thread check whether the event is set instead of just infinitely looping.

```
while not event.is_set():
    relatively_fast_computation()
```

The main thread waits for a result on the queue, and when one is received, sets the event. The worker threads then notice this the next pass through the while loop and quit. This is probably the preferred way, as it allows the worker threads to properly exit, cleanup, close files, etc.

The issue here is that this will not work well if each pass through the while loop is very slow, and it won't work at all if the functions inside there truly block, as in network I/O. In that case, there are workarounds, but none of them sound great or particularly applicable to your situation.

Edit:

And as was also pointed out in the comments, if the `node.mine()` method is a pure CPython function, then threading here is probably useless. The GIL will prevent CPU-bound code like hashing from running more than one thread anyway. Use `multiprocessing`.

Comment: So I'll try the first approach of using events first. You want me to try adding an event/flag to the argument tuple of the thread before I start it? Wont this only be checked once?

Comment: Create the event in the main thread, pass it to the target function as an argument, and check the event on each pass through the loop. Something like `while not event.is_set(): compute_sha(other_data)`.

Comment: And it should be set after the loop?

Comment: One thread finishes, and writes its result to the queue. The main thread waits for a result on the queue, then sets the event after it retrieves one. All other threads will see the event is set on the next iteration, and return.

Comment: In what way is it failing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167057/discussion-between-bnaecker-and-ninesalt).